# Get another function's parameter types for use in another function's ...rest parameter

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-generics, react-native-firebase

For some background, I am trying to write a function that can call any existing method of React Native Firebase Analytics within an Expo project that is accounting for whether the app is running in Expo Go or not. If it is, I don't call the `analytics()` method since it isn't available.

The Firebase Analytics method types are available as a class: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/566470cfc0e919a46c0a119835187257bf046df7/packages/analytics/lib/index.d.ts#L801

What I'm trying to do is use a generic type that lets me pass in the name of the method I want to call, and then grab the types of the parameters of that method and apply them to the `...rest` parameter. The generic type seems to work for the method name, but I can't get the type for `...rest` correct. This is what I have:

```
import { FirebaseAnalyticsTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

import { isExpoGo } from '~/environment';

let analytics; // Also unclear how to type this
if (!isExpoGo) {
    analytics = require('@react-native-firebase/analytics').default;
}

/**
 * Call a Firebase Analytics function.
 */
export const analyticsFn = async function <
    F extends keyof FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module
>(fnName: F, ...rest: Parameters<FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module[F]>) {
    console.log('Analytics:', fnName, ...rest);
    if (isExpoGo) return;
    return await analytics()[fnName](...rest);
};
```

The part within `Parameters<>` is throwing this error:

```
Type 'Module[F]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type '((name: string, params?: { [key: string]: any; } | undefined, options?: AnalyticsCallOptions | undefined) => Promise<void>) | ((enabled: boolean) => Promise<...>) | ... 44 more ... | FirebaseApp' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
```

I also tried `Parameters<typeof FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module[F]>` but it's getting autoformatted to `Parameters<(typeof FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module)[F]>`, which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering is related to the constraint on the *Parameters type*. The Parameters utility type expects a function type as its argument, but in this case, you are trying to access a method from an object type `FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module` using the key F. To fix this, I would recommend that you extract the actual function type from the module and apply it to the Parameters utility type. It would look something like this:

```html
import { FirebaseAnalyticsTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

import { isExpoGo } from '~/environment';

/**
 * Call a Firebase Analytics function.
 */
export const analyticsFn = async function <
    F extends keyof FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module
>(fnName: F, ...rest: Parameters<FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module[F]>
) {
    console.log('Analytics:', fnName, ...rest);
    if (isExpoGo) return;
    return await analytics()[fnName](...rest);
};
```

This should work correctly now. The `Parameters<FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module[F]>` will properly infer the parameter types of the function corresponding to fnName from the `FirebaseAnalyticsTypes.Module` object.

:) Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused, this code you've suggested looks exactly like the code I provided, which doesn't work.